# Can you directly connect one computer (a back up PC) to another (the main PC), and access the main PCs bios using the back up PC?

Tags: bios, remote-desktop

**Summary of question: how can I remotely access a computers bios if windows fails to boot?**

I run a remote observatory for astrophotgraphy and the kit is controlled by a computer located in the obseratory. I remote in using Teamviewer.

Recently I have found that the computer doesn't boot windows but instead requires me to go to set up and review the bios settings. This isn't a problem aside from the fact that if this happens, I can't access the computer remotely.

I have looked into the lantronix spider KVM as way of accessing the computers bios remotely. However, I have a small NUC that I am not using.

My question:

Is it possible to physically connect one computer to another and mirror the computers screen that is failing to boot windows. If this were possible, I could remote into the back up NUC and access the bios of the main computer.

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Replace the cmos battery in the machine that is loosing settings. Typically it is a CR2032 battery.

Comment: Accessing the console to troubleshoot boot issues requires something like an [IPMI card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) or another Lights-Out/DRAC type management card which are typically found in servers. This would require a compatible system or motherboard. It's better to just repair the current system (by replacing the CMOS battery), or replace it if it can't be repaired.

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is to resolve the issue which prevents the system from booting. It's highly likely that the machine in the observatory has a flat CMOS battery, which is why it's not retaining the BIOS information. Replace the CMOS battery, set up your BIOS profile and save it, then power down. Ensure when you power back up, the machine boots as you'd expect.